# Use alt with react in ES6

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, alt

I'm trying to use alt with React and code an Action in ES6 style:

```
import alt from '../alt';

class LoginActions {
  login() {
    alert('oi');
  }
}

export default alt.createActions(LoginActions);
```

My .babelrc is using class transformation plugin:

```
// without options
{
    "plugins": ["transform-class-properties"]
}
```

My package.json is configured with babel and webpack

```
{
  "name": "npm-yarn-babel-webpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "6",
    "babel-loader": "7",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.10.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "webpack": "^4.25.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "alt": "^0.18.6",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack -p",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --hot --inline"
  }
```

I Have a component Hello World:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import LoginActions from './LoginActions';

export class HelloWorld extends Component {


    render() {
        return (
            <div className="hello-world">
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default HelloWorld;
```

I'm running as:

```
yarn run dev
```

If I do not import LoginActions, it works, when I import, it compiles, but it does not work.

If I a run with react-scripts it show me an error that alt can understand ES6 class definition.

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have `alt` in your package.json so you can do: `import alt from 'alt';`

Comment: I need instantiate alt before call it, I do it in the alt.js file and import alt instantiate

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: You need to put all the code in here. and it would be better if you also add http://codsandbox.io too

Comment: https://github.com/ivanfcfilho/temp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your babel-loader is only configured for .jsx files. You need to configure it for .js file too which `alt.js` is. To do that use the regex `/\.jsx?/`

```
   {
         test: /\.jsx?/,
         use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: { presets: ['react', 'es2015'] }
         }
     },
```